# combineLatest but remove completed observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs

How can I combine the latest values but remove the completed observables dynamically? The `combineLatest` operator does not remove completed observables, it just repeats the last value they emitted until all observables complete.

I wanted something like this:

```js
combineLatestAlive([interval(100).pipe(take(2)), interval(100)]).subscribe(console.log)

//[0,0]
//[1,0]
//[1,1]
//[1]
//[2] ... and so on
```

Comment: You may want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72115266/5699993)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added two operators.

1. endWith: Append end mark like undefined
2. map: Transform array

```js
combineLatest([interval(100).pipe(take(2), endWith(undefined)), interval(100)]).pipe(
    map(values => values.filter(v => v !== undefined))
  ).subscribe(console.log);
```

result is: (your wanted result has `[1, 1]` but `[1,` is already completed value.)

```
[ 0, 0 ]
[ 1, 0 ]
[ 0 ]
[ 1 ]
[ 2 ]
...
```

Comment: Why didd you use `reduce` and not `filter`?

Comment: @GabrielMachado You're right. I've fixed code with `filter`.